# ubuntu 11.10 login goes back to splash screen

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-11.10, vmware-player

I'm running ubuntu 11.10 on a vmware 4.0 player. I'm having a problem and hope you can help.

When I log into the splash screen, ubuntu will take my password but promptly return me to the splash screen. This only happens with 1 user (another user logs in fine). When I log in with   F1, I am able to log in successfully (one note: it throws an error "export: 29: : bad variable name").

I've tried to: remove the .config/gnome-session directory and modified permissions on /tmp (sudo chmod -R a+w /tmp) as described here:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1139558&page=3 (I know it's the wrong version, but worth a shot.)

I've also tried Alt+SysRq+R+S+E+I+U+B as described here: http://www.botskool.com/forum/computer-programming/linuxunix/restartshutdown-frozen-linuxubuntu

Finally, I removed .Xsession and installed libglib2.0 as described here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/81147/endless-login-loop

Any other suggestions or resources to check? 
TIA,

Joe

Here is the .bashrc:

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return

# don't put duplicate lines in the history. See bash(1) for more options
# ... or force ignoredups and ignorespace
HISTCONTROL=ignoredups:ignorespace

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "$debian_chroot" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ] && ! shopt -oq posix; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
fi
```

Comment: Adding this comment in case anyone else is interested. To log in to the terminal (referred to as the F1 method in the questions), when you're in the login screen, press the <shift> <ctrl> <f1>, which will bring you to the terminal (and access to your profile(s)). [documentation](http://linux.about.com/od/ubuntu_doc/a/ubudg24t8.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you modify the default .bashrc in your home folder ? Like an "exec something" ?

I know this can sounds strange but I had a similar problem even though I was working with KDE instead of gnome.

Well, by the way, could you post your .bashrc ? Especially lines 25 to 35.

Comment: Thanks @delannoyk. I remembered that I changed .profile, which seemed to have caused the error. I took out the lines I added, and now I can log in.